# Android Emulator GenyMotion(w/ VirtualBox) causes New 13'' Macbook Pro Yosemite 10.10.2 to crash

Tags: macos, virtualbox, genymotion

Whenever I start running any Android emulator on GenyMotion (2.3 and 2.4) with VirtualBox, my Macbook pro crashes..I am using (Yosemite 10.10.2.  8G memory).

A large rectangular message box comes up in the middle of my screen telling me the operating system has crashed, press the power button to reboot

```
Anonymous UUID:       4EADEF34-9315-1DDE-1AC3-ACDD85606B75

Sun Mar 15 15:07:58 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 0 caller 0xffffff801c41b532): Kernel trap at 0xffffff815ca3a7f0, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0x0000000105c9a3e0, CR3: 0x000000007988a094, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0
RAX: 0x0000000105c9a3e0, RBX: 0x0000000000000000, RCX: 0x000000000000000a, RDX: 0x0000000000000000
RSP: 0xffffff8128585f50, RBP: 0xffffff8128585f50, RSI: 0x0000000000000001, RDI: 0x0000000000000015
R8:  0x0000000000000000, R9:  0xffffff8128585ea8, R10: 0x0000000105c9a2a0, R11: 0x0000000000000015
R12: 0xffffff814d698000, R13: 0x0000000000000000, R14: 0xffffff7f9e9d10a0, R15: 0xffffff8128585fc0
RFL: 0x0000000000010202, RIP: 0xffffff815ca3a7f0, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0x0000000105c9a3e0, Error code: 0x0000000000000001, Fault CPU: 0x0 SMAP fault

Backtrace (CPU 0), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff8128585c00 : 0xffffff801c330e41 
0xffffff8128585c80 : 0xffffff801c41b532 
0xffffff8128585e40 : 0xffffff801c4377a3 
0xffffff8128585e60 : 0xffffff815ca3a7f0 
0xffffff8128585f50 : 0xffffff815ca1b550 
0xffffff8128585f70 : 0xffffff815ca390eb 
0xffffff8128585fb0 : 0xffffff815cacbc5e 
0xffffff814ed539d0 : 0xffffff815ca3942d 
0xffffff814ed53a10 : 0xffffff7f9e9a098a 
0xffffff814ed53ab0 : 0xffffff7f9e9a8610 
0xffffff814ed53b30 : 0xffffff801c583739 
0xffffff814ed53b80 : 0xffffff801c572016 
0xffffff814ed53c10 : 0xffffff801c566eb3 
0xffffff814ed53e00 : 0xffffff801c7af5cb 
0xffffff814ed53e30 : 0xffffff801c7ee5e4 
0xffffff814ed53f50 : 0xffffff801c84c756 
0xffffff814ed53fb0 : 0xffffff801c437fa6 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv(4.3.24)[C630E3FD-59E0-3B8E-1458-CF270CD5318E]@0xffffff7f9e998000->0xffffff7f9e9effff

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: VBoxHeadless

Mac OS version:
14C2507

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.1.1: Thu Feb 26 22:41:49 PST 2015; root:xnu-2782.15.5~1/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: BFED45FB-0D4F-31C5-99F2-E43D9D06E69C
Kernel slide:     0x000000001c000000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff801c200000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff801c100000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 11721472706156
last loaded kext at 4814087606175: com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient   3.7.4 (addr 0xffffff7f9ea09000, size 36864)
last unloaded kext at 5034517914826: com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC   4.2.2b5 (addr 0xffffff7f9ea03000, size 16384)
loaded kexts:
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.24
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.24
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.24
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.24
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.AGPM   100.16.12
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.1.9d0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   269.44
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.0.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.31.0
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.3f4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.0.4
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.6.0
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.3
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 35
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.0
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 64.3
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   920.28.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.10
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 269.44
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.9.5
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.3f4
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.3f4
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.9.5
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.9.2
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.8.9d5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 269.44
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 269.44
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.4
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.4
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.15.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    41.2
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  262.45
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.1
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   720.56
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  41.2
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.7 GHz, 8 GB, SMC 2.28f6
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 4 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x80AD, 0x483943434E4E4E424C54414C41522D4E5544
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.162.45.4)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.3f4 15437, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Wi-Fi, AirPort, en0
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0256G, 251 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1
```

Comment: Even though GenyMotion is a programming tool, this will probably still be nominated for closure as off topic; it's definitely more hardware related than anything.  SuperUser might be a better place to post.  However, I can suggest you might be experiencing issues because you can't use GenyMotion and Paralells on the same machine, and Paralells is very common on Macbooks. https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/genymotion-users/bkJQ7bxOxTw/

Answer (score 16, accepted):

After around 6-8 hours of searching internet, talked to the support from Apple. I finally found the resolution from VirtualBox.org.

It was because of the underline VirtualBox failed running on the new release Apple 13'' Macbook Pro.  According to ama1122 from VirtualBox.

> This appears to be an issue with the new 13-inch MacBook Pro with
>   Retina Display. The key bit is this: "Fault CPU: 0x2 SMAP fault".
>   Any panic that includes the "SMAP fault" marker is the same problem.

The new build for VirtualBox VirtualBox-4.3.25-98914-OSX will do the trick. You can download it from the link below:

https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Testbuilds

I understand this subject is a little off the topic of software development.  However, I hope this will help any software developer who has the new 13'' Macbook Pro with Retina display and trying to build an Android development environment on top of that.

Comment: This helps a lot. It works well with VirtualBox 4.3.28. GenyMotion suggests to use VirtualBox 4.3.12 for better performance, but it causes MacOS crash.

Comment: Thank you very much, also VirtualBox-4.3.37-105748-OSX seems to do the job. If it can be useful I can also suggest to use smcFanControl that you can download from here http://www.eidac.de/ . As by my personal experience running the fan at high rpm when using genymotion avoided so many crashes (I was able to work for 2-3 hours before the mac crashes).